# secure express js http end point from one place via passport.authenticate

Tags: node.js, api, express, azure-active-directory, restful-url

so we have node.js restful API,

we're using this https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad to secure our endpoints.

but problem is, we have more than 50 endpoints, and everywhere we do not want to define

```
 passport.authenticate("oauth-bearer", { session: false })
```

Sample HTTP END POINT :

```
router.post(
  "/accounts",
  passport.authenticate("oauth-bearer", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    // Check mandatory request parameters
    if (!req.body.user || !req.body.currency) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Missing parameters" });
    }
```

let's say we have 50 endpoints, everywhere we do not want to define

```
 passport.authenticate("oauth-bearer", { session: false })
```

is there is way, where I can write at the commonplace and every endpoint exposed by the project is secured?

the closest I found this : ( but this post is from 2013, so I am not sure it is "preferred way" )

http://beletsky.net/2013/10/securing-express-dot-js-http-endpoints.html

do you think, I can do it this way?  how do you practice this in your application?

Thanks,